# Accessing Variables from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have a Main class of game named BrickBreaker

```
public class BrickBreaker extends Activity {
  // there is lot of other code but i am only pointing to the issue
  class BreakoutView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    // The size of the screen in pixels
    int screenX;
    int screenY;

    // Get a Display object to access screen details
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        // Load the resolution into a Point object
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        screenX = size.x;
        screenY = size.y;
}}
```

And from another class (below) I want to access `screenX` from the Main class:

```
public class Paddle {

  // This the the constructor method
// When we create an object from this class we will pass
// in the screen width and height
public Paddle(int screenX, int screenY){
    // 130 pixels wide and 20 pixels high
    length = 130;
    height = 20;

    // Start paddle in roughly the sceen centre
    x = screenX / 2;
    y = screenY - 20;

    rect = new RectF(x, y, x + length, y + height);

    // How fast is the paddle in pixels per second
    paddleSpeed = 550;

}
  public void update(long fps){
    rect.left = x;
      rect.right = x + length;
      if (x<0){
         x=0;
      }
      else if (x+length > screenX){
         x = screenX-length;
      }
   }
}
```

How can I access `screenX` from the `Paddle` class?

Comment: By making `screenX` accessible. Either by making it public, or by providing a getter for it, and by giving `Paddle` a reference to your `BrickBreaker` object.

Comment: I am totally not good in java please tell me that how can I make it accessible using both of the methods you explained. please @cello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Paddle class modify field screenX

Java static variable

If you declare any variable as static, it is known static variable.

The static variable can be used to refer the common property of all objects (that is not unique for each object) e.g. company name of employees,college name of students etc.
The static variable gets memory only once in class area at the time of class loading.
Advantage of static variable

Please check this : [STATIC](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java)

It makes your program memory efficient (i.e it saves memory).

```
public class Paddle {

public static int screenX;

  // This the the constructor method
// When we create an object from this class we will pass
// in the screen width and height
public Paddle(int screenX, int screenY){
this.screenX = screenX;
    // 130 pixels wide and 20 pixels high
    length = 130;
    height = 20;

    // Start paddle in roughly the sceen centre
    x = screenX / 2;
    y = screenY - 20;

    rect = new RectF(x, y, x + length, y + height);

    // How fast is the paddle in pixels per second
    paddleSpeed = 550;

}
  public void update(long fps){
    rect.left = x;
      rect.right = x + length;
      if (x<0){
         x=0;
      }
      else if (x+length > screenX){
         x = screenX-length;
      }
   }
}
```

And to acces in BrickBeaker you need to:

```
Paddle.screenX
```

Enjoy

Comment: I would not recommend a static variable for this.

Comment: You are my boss, you approaches my mental level and you explained whatever i was able to understand easily. one more thing need to know. if i don't declare it as static what is the effect of it on code? i mean won't i able to access it from BrickBreaker or any other issue? @Rod

Comment: See updated answer. Yea you cant acces non static field in class. With static you can do this.

Comment: @cello your answer is correct too but Rod explained it in easy way. If possible i could accept both of your answers. I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

You need to get access to BreakoutView's member `screenX` from your `Paddle` class.

For this, your Paddle class first needs to get access to the BreakoutView instance.

You could do this by passing it for example in the constructor:

```
public class Paddle {
  BreakoutView view;
  public Paddle (BreakoutView view) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  public void update(long fps){
    ...
  }
}
```

And where you create it:

```
BreakoutView view = new BreakoutView(.....);
Paddle paddle = new Paddle(view);
....
```

Next, you need to get access to the `screenX` member. There are two options:

First: make it public:

```
// The size of the screen in pixels
public int screenX;
public int screenY;
```

With this solution, you could access it in your `Paddle` class with `this.view.screenX`.

But this would allow other code, for example from inside your Paddle class, to modify these values, which is often not desired. Thus, the safer way is:

Second: Provide a getter.

In BreakoutView, add the following method:

```
public int getScreenX() {
  return this.screenX;
}
```

and then, in your `Paddle` class, you could access it like `this.view.getScreenX()` instead of just `screenX`.

Comment: I already have a constructor method in paddle class and i am unable to create another one. now i want to use screenX into update method but i don't know how can i do that @cello please help, i have edited the code above with paddle constructor.

Comment: Add a member `int screenX` to Paddle class, and in your Paddle constructor, assign it like `this.screenX = screenX`. Then you can use screenX in the update method.